# Using R, how can I create and index using principal components?

Tags: r, indexing, pca

I have already done PCA analysis- and obtained three principal components- but I don´t know how to transform these into an index.
I know, for example, in Stata there ir a command " predict index, score" but I am not finding the way to do this in R.
What I want to do is to create a socioeconomic index, from variables such as level of education, internet access, etc, using PCA.
Thank you!

Comment: You have three components so you have 3 indices that are represented by the principal component scores. The `predict` function will take new data and estimate the scores. Without more information and reproducible data it is not possible to be more specific.

Comment: You might have a better time looking up tutorials on PCA in R, trying out some code, and coming back here with a specific question on the code & data you have. Take a look again at the [mcve] guidance

Comment: An index is like 1 score? meaning you want to consolidate the 3 principal components into 1 metric

Comment: @StupidWolf yes!! precisely :D i dont know which command could help me do this.

Comment: do you have a dependent variable? or what are you going to use this metric for? I suspect what the stata command does is to use the PCs for prediction, and the score is the probability

Comment: @dcarlson yes, i would like to obtain my scores to use them as an index. I have obtained my components by `my_pca<-prcomp(ind.scale)`  and `my_pca$rotation`. Do you know how can I get the scores to use them as the mentioned index?

Comment: `my_pca$scores`. You can find out what information `prcomp` returns by reading the manual page using the command `?prcomp`. The section titled "Value" provides the details.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I use the PCA scores as an index. See an example below:

```
# Load the psych package, you could also use princomp in the stats package
library(psych)

# Example data
df <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100, 0, .5)
                 , x2 = rnorm(100, 0, 1)
                 , x3 = rnorm(100, .02, 1)
)


# run the PCA
PCA_results <- principal(df, nfactors = 1)

# add our PCA scores as an index
df$index <- PCA_results$scores
```

You could rescale the scores if you want them to be on a 0-1 scale.

Comment: Yes! I was thinking of using the scores. But I am not finding the command tu do it in R. What you are showing me might help me, thank you! But I did my PCA differently. I used `my_pca<-prcomp(ind.scale)` , should `df$index <- PCA_results$scores` help me anyways?

Comment: @Queen_S, yep! if you are using the stats package function, I would use princomp() instead of prcomp since it provide more output, for example `PCA_results <- princomp(df)



df$index <- PCA_results$scores[1] 
`

Comment: @Jacob,  Hi I am also trying to get an Index with the PCA, may I know why you recommend using PCA_results$scores as the index? PCA_results$scores is PC1 right?

Comment: @kaix, You are right! PCA_results$scores provides PC1. There's a ton of stuff out there on PCA scores, so I won't write-up a full response here, but in general, since this is a composite of x1, x2, x3 (in my example code), it captures that maximum variance across those within a single variable. Basically, you get the explanatory value of the three variables in a single index variable that can be scaled from 1-0. Also, feel free to upvote my initial response if you found it helpful!